# Why would IT lock down SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, group-policy

### Question:

Why would anyone lock down the SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege == *Increase a process working set* == https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-a-process-working-set from it's default value of "Default Users" to Administrators only?

I'm not asking for theoretical technical tidbits, but I would be interested to find out whether any Windows Administration Pros know a source or consider tightening of this setting useful?

### Background:

We had a "DOS" by customer's central IT on our Oracle 21c installations on site.

After new Security Policies had been rolled out, OracleServiceXE as well as Oracle's Listener Service failed to start with error:

`1297` *"A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration"*

Long story short, these services declare `RequiredPrivileges` (see `sc qprivs`):

```
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege **
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

Now, the customer's IT rolled out a change that set `SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege` from it default of "Default Users" to the 3 SIDs: `*S-1-5-19` (Local Service), `*S-1-5-32-544` (Administrators), `*S-1-5-90-0` (Windows Manager\Windows Manager Group)

With this, it's "obvious" how the Service Control Manager then refused to start the service, as it simply was missing the SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege. (It being configured with a `NT SERVICE\*` account.)

Fiddling with this setting seems rather baffling to me. Any insights?

Comment: Insight would be "assess the current environment and test before deploy".

Comment: @GregAskew - exactly. Just that we're not the ones deploying it, but customer's IT. And then the customer's engineers come to us complaining that the system stopped working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Locking down the `SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege` privilege is a security measure to restrict processes from increasing their working set size, which could have implications for system stability and resource allocation. This privilege allows a process to allocate more memory than it would typically be allowed.

By limiting this privilege, the system aims to prevent potential abuses or unintended consequences, such as denial-of-service attacks through excessive memory consumption or unauthorized access to sensitive data.

Comment: Sorry, but this reads like a very canned answer. Specifically, what would this have to do with "... unauthorized access to sensitive data." ??

Comment: If a threat actor is able to increase the memory, he might be able to access more data, and process it in memory to encrypt it or upload it